# How can I run Python on Windows?

Tags: python

I want to create some project using Python. For PHP, we can simply install XAMPP and start working.

However, I have been struggling to find a similar installer for Python for half and hour now. I am reading this guide: https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/windows.html. I keep clicking on links called with text "Python Launcher for Windows", "Full Installer" etc. However, they keep taking me to some other webpages.

I can't seem to find any actual executable for running Python. Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

I visited the webiste. Clicked on Downloads. Scrolled Down to Windows Users and then Clicked on Embedded Distribution. I didn't know there were download links at the bottom of the page.

In my humble opinion, any files meant for Windows users to download should be present in a section titled "Windows users".

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/, click the "Download XYZ" links…?

Comment: Probably because it's pretty straight-forward. Start at the [home page](https://www.python.org/), and look for the "downloads" section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download Windows Python installer from here:
   https://www.python.org/downloads/
2. Install it
3. Check that path to python binary exists in PATH
4. Open terminal and run: *python*

Answer (score 1):

1. Open a browser window and navigate to the Download page for Windows at python.org. https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/
2. Underneath the heading at the top that says Python Releases for Windows, click on the link for the Latest Python 3 Release - Python 3.x.x.
3. Scroll to the bottom and select either Windows x86-64 executable installer for 64-bit or Windows x86 executable installer for 32-bit.
4. Run the installer and it's done